# Want to get email but they provide wrong output

Tags: python, web-scraping, xpath, scrapy

I want to get `email` but they will provide wrong output these is page link https://zoekeenadvocaat.advocatenorde.nl/advocaten/soesterberg/mevrouw-mr-mm-strengers/11094237420

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
import time
from scrapy_selenium import SeleniumRequest
import re

 
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'test'
    page_number=1
    def start_requests(self):
        yield SeleniumRequest(
                    url = "https://zoekeenadvocaat.advocatenorde.nl/zoeken?q=&type=advocaten&limiet=10&sortering=afstand&filters%5Brechtsgebieden%5D=%5B%5D&filters%5Bspecialisatie%5D=0&filters%5Btoevoegingen%5D=0&locatie%5Badres%5D=Holland&locatie%5Bgeo%5D%5Blat%5D=52.132633&locatie%5Bgeo%5D%5Blng%5D=5.291266&locatie%5Bstraal%5D=56&locatie%5Bhash%5D=67eb2b8d0aab60ec69666532ff9527c9&weergave=lijst&pagina=1",
                    wait_time = 3,
                    screenshot = True,
                    callback = self.parse,
                    dont_filter = True
                )
  
    def parse(self, response):
        books = response.xpath("//span[@class='h4 no-margin-bottom']//a//@href").extract()
        for book in books:
            url = response.urljoin(book)
            yield Request(url, callback=self.parse_book)
              
    def parse_book(self, response):
        title=response.css(".title h3::text").get()
        advocaten=response.css(".secondary::text").get()
        detail=response.xpath("//section[@class='lawyer-info']")
        for i in range(len(detail)):
            if re.search("@",detail[i].get()):
                d1=detail[i].xpath("//div[@class='column small-9']//a//@href").get()
                print(d1)
```

Comment: Can you define what "wrong output" means?

Comment: they will provide me a phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `xpath` that it selects the second element:

```
(//div[@class='column small-9'])[2]/a/@href
```

Example: http://xpather.com/Hhjolrh1

---

Alternative would be to select it directly:

```
//a[starts-with(@href, 'mailto')]/@href
```

Example: http://xpather.com/EtD8noeI

Answer (score -1):

You get the phone number because it is the first element that fits 'column small-9'.

As an alternative to the answer with X-Path, here a solution without X-Path:

```
soup.find("span", string="E-mail").parent.find_next("div").find("a").contents[0]
```

Comment: I know that but how to access the email these is my point

Comment: This option seems to be more correct, if some element is not displayed then xPath will show incorrect information. But I would do this - `soup.find("span", string="E-mail").find_next("div").getText()`